# How do I iterate through a record in F# and create a data transformation into a new record

Tags: f#

I am trying to use fsharp to parse a file and convert it to a data model.

```
let name = 'Ron'    
let date = '10/6/2020'
let rawData =
     [|{
     time = 15
     pressure = 50
     force = 100};
     {time = 16
     pressure = 55
     force = 110};
     {time = 17
     pressure = 60
     force = 120
     }|]
```

I am looking to transform the data into a .csv but my intermediate step will be to get it in a record. The output desired is shown below.

```
name  |   date    |  parameter  |  value
_______________________________________
 Ron  | 10/6/2020 |     time    |  15
 Ron  | 10/6/2020 |   pressure  |  50
 Ron  | 10/6/2020 |    force    |  100
 Ron  | 10/6/2020 |     time    |  16
 Ron  | 10/6/2020 |   pressure  |  55
 Ron  | 10/6/2020 |    force    |  110
 Ron  | 10/6/2020 |     time    |  17
 Ron  | 10/6/2020 |   pressure  |  60
 Ron  | 10/6/2020 |    force    |  120
```

I know that I need to create a new record but how do I add constants in this way.

Answer (score 2):

Your question does not make it very clear what exactly are you struggling with. However, if I wanted to solve this problem, I would probably use the [Deedle data frame library](https://fslab.org/Deedle). Given your data with correct indentation:

```
let name = "Ron"
let date = "10/6/2020"
let rawData =
  [|  {| time = 15; pressure = 50; force = 100|}
      {| time = 16; pressure = 55; force = 110|}
      {| time = 17; pressure = 60; force = 120|} |]
```

You can turn it into a CSV file by mapping over raw data and creating a tuple with the constants and the data itself. Once you have this, you can turn it into a data frame using `ofRecords`. The clever thing in Deedle is the `expandAllCols` function which turns nested records into multiple columns, so you end up with a data frame with five columns:

```
let df = 
  rawData
  |> Array.map (fun data -> name, date, data)
  |> Frame.ofRecords
  |> Frame.expandAllCols 1
  |> Frame.indexColsWith ["name";"date";"time";"pressure";"force"]

df.SaveCsv("c:/temp/test.csv", includeRowKeys=false)
```

The column names that you get by using tuples and expand are ugly, so I rename them using `indexColsWith` and then we can save the file as a CSV.

Comment: I am unable to get that code to work I get  `testing.fsx(124,1): error FS0010: Unexpected infix operator in interaction` when I run `|> Frame.indexColsWith ["name";"date";"time";"pressure";"force"]`